# Why is this not a closure that allows an inner function to access an outer function variable?

Tags: javascript, closures, prototype

How do I enable access to variable 'e' in funcB via a closure?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
Test = function () {};
Test.prototype.funcA = function (k)  {
    var that = this;
    return  function(e) {
        window.console.log('k: ' + k); // 'abc'
        window.console.log('e: ' + e); // 'def'
        that.funcB(k);
    };
};
Test.prototype.funcB = function (p) {
    window.console.log('p: ' + p); // 'abc'
    window.console.log('e: ' + e); // undefined (why?)
}
obj = new Test();
(obj.funcA('abc'))('def');
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm confused about closures.

Since variable e exists in funcA (printed 'def'), why can funcB not access it since funcB is executed by funcA?  How do I give funcB access to variable e?

I want variable e to be accessible via a closure.  I don't want to store it on the instantiated object (which I know I could do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to pass the value of "e" to the other function as a parameter. Scoping in JavaScript is determined by the lexical relationship of functions, not the dynamic relationship. Code in a function can see "outwards", and moving out from `funcB()` does not encounter a scope with "e" defined. The only symbols visible to code in `funcB()` are its own local symbols (`p` in this case) and global symbols.

Now, you could explicitly stash a copy of "e" on the object itself as a property:

```
return  function(e) {
    window.console.log('k: ' + k); // 'abc'
    window.console.log('e: ' + e); // 'def'

    that.e = e;
    return that.funcB(k);
};

Test.prototype.funcB = function (p) {
    window.console.log('p: ' + p); // 'abc'
    window.console.log('e: ' + this.e);
}
```

Comment: I'd rather not pass it in either.  Is there no way to use closures to enable funcB to have access to variable e?

Comment: I think I see what you're saying.  Since funcB is not contained lexically in funcA (it's only executed by funcA), there is no closure involved.

Comment: @ChrisG. yes, basically. Scoping is static.

Comment: @ChrisG. answer updated - an alternative to passing it as a parameter is to save it on the object.

Comment: Barring some better idea, I'll go this route then.  Thank you!